# How to loop API Calls Swift after parsing data

Tags: ios, swift, api, loops

I'm currently making an API call to return a bunch of JSON data, parsing it, and then sorting it based on a few different criteria. After the JSON data is parsed (it pulls back a bunch of recipes), it's filtered through a few functions that trim the results pool to more accurately fit what the user requested (ie. User only wants recipes that take less than 30 minutes to prepare) .

Sometimes after all these filters there are no more recipes left! - When that happens id like to re-call the API again automatically. I'm not really sure how to do this without creating an infinite loop of some sort - code below:

```
    SLApiCall.sharedCall.callGetApi(SearchUrl, params: dictPara) { (response, err ) -> () in

        var data = response!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        var localError: NSError?
        var jsonobj: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError) as? NSDictionary

        var arrTemp : NSArray = (jsonobj?.valueForKey("matches") as? NSArray)!

        var totalMatches = jsonobj.valueForKey("totalMatchCount") as! Int
        User.currentUser.setTotalRecipesMatched(totalMatches)
        let (max, min) = User.currentUser.ingredientsCountBasedOnLazyOption()

        printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode("test12345") {

            self.arrRecipes = self.SortingArray(arrTemp.arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks(), maxLimit: max, minLimit: min)
        // This is where all the sorting happens, if this returns an empty array I want to re-call the method. 

        }

        User.currentUser.setList(self.arrRecipes!, param: theJSONText as! String)

        self.assignDemoData()

    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, especially this "In the event that the data passed back, after being filtered through step 1-5, no longer has any data left".
Can you reformulate ?

Comment: @AncAinu edited for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that ? If there is no recipes left to show, if would be better to tell it to the user, isn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution for your problem is using repeat-while using a semaphore to employ a wait for the asynchronous call. Be aware though that, trying to do this in main thread might block your UI, so might want it to do in a secondary thread/queue. Also updating UI, etc must be done in main thread:

```
repeat{

  dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

  var gotData  = false

  SLApiCall.sharedCall.callGetApi(SearchUrl, params: dictPara) { (response, err ) -> () in

    var data = response!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    var localError: NSError?
    var jsonobj: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError) as? NSDictionary

    var arrTemp : NSArray = (jsonobj?.valueForKey("matches") as? NSArray)!

    var totalMatches = jsonobj.valueForKey("totalMatchCount") as! Int
    User.currentUser.setTotalRecipesMatched(totalMatches)
    let (max, min) = User.currentUser.ingredientsCountBasedOnLazyOption()

    printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode("test12345") {

      self.arrRecipes = self.SortingArray(arrTemp.arrayByReplacingNullsWithBlanks(), maxLimit: max, minLimit: min)
      // This is where all the sorting happens, if this returns an empty array I want to re-call the method.
      if(self.arrRecipea.count){
        gotData = true

      }

    }

    User.currentUser.setList(self.arrRecipes!, param: theJSONText as! String)

    self.assignDemoData()
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem)
  }

  //Wait until the block is called
  dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); //Note- have a meaningful timeout here

}while (gotData != true)
```

Comment: Thanks nshebbar, could you elaborate on what you're doing with dispatch_semaphore_t? I'm just learning to code and I understand threading but only at a very basic level. I do understand the concept of dispatching this to a different thread so the UI can load and not lag and wait for the callback.

Comment: Basically, I achieve the 'waiting' for an asynchronous call (necessarily happening in a  secondary thread) using the semaphore. dispatch_semaphore_wait  will block until the associated semaphore is 'signalled' - in our case the asynchronous callback here.